# Detecting whether a ViewModel's associated View is showing/not showing

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have some ViewModels where I use a Service, which is quite bandwidth intensive. However this service is only required when viewing specific Views in the application.

In MvvmCross vNext I used the `ViewUnRegistered`/`ViewRegistered` events to detect when a `ViewModel` was shown, and had a `BaseViewModel` which looked something like this:

```
public class BaseViewModel 
    : MvxViewModel
    , IMvxServiceConsumer
{
    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        ViewUnRegistered += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!HasViews)
            {
                OnViewsDetached();
            }
        };

        ViewRegistered += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (HasViews)
            {
                OnViewsAttached();
            }
        };
    }

    public virtual void OnViewsAttached()
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    public virtual void OnViewsDetached()
    {
        // nothing to do in this base class
    }
}
```

Then in my other `ViewModel`s I would just inherit from this and override `OnViewsAttached` and `OnViewsDetached` to start and stop the service.

Now in MvvmCross v3 these two `Event`s are not present anymore. As I understand they were not working properly on iOS either. v3 also has a new `ViewModel` life cycle, which has `SavedState` and `ReloadState`. Although as I understand it `SavedState` only gets called in the `ViewModel` is destroyed, which might not be the case even though it is not showing.

As to detecting whether the associated View is showing, one could assume that a View is showing when `ShowViewModel` is called and have some `Init` parameters in the view, but the tricky part here is to detect when a View is not showing any more. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This area of determining View/ViewModel lifecycle across all the platforms is fairly tricky, especially once developers start straying from the 'basic' presentation models and start using tabs, splitviews, popups, flyouts, etc

MvvmCross v3 doesn't currently have a common way to handle this.

The previous code from vNext was broken when ios6 removed `viewDidUnload` (but was generally wrongly used anyway - as `viewDidUnload` was not generally called when ViewModel developers thought it would be!)

There is an issue open still to discuss possible future common ideas... https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/74

---

With that said, some of the patterns I've recently used for this type of situation are:

- for most viewmodels I do nothing - since these viewmodels don't consume any resources and can just be garbage collected when the system needs the memory back.
- for ViewModels which consume low-intensity resources - like timer ticks, then I generally use the `MvxMessenger` to connect the ViewModel to those resources. This messenger uses weak referencing by default and itself sends out [subscription change messages](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Messenger/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger/MvxSubscriberChangeMessage.cs) when clients subscribe/unsubscribe

  Using this method, I can allow the background resources to monitor whether the viewmodels are in memory (and referenced by views) - and so the background resources can manage themselves.

  ... although actually quite often (e.g. for timer ticks) then I leave the background resources constantly running regardless of whether a ViewModel is listening.
- for those rare situations where resource monitoring is actively needed - e.g. for the SpheroViewModel which needs to maintain an active BlueTooth SPP channel - then I implement a custom interface on the ViewModel - e.g. `IActiveViewModel` - and then I hook into that interface from the vies on each of the various platforms

  Generally I do this from ViewDidAppear/Disappear, OnNavigatedTo/From, OnRestart/Pause - but whether this exact timing works for you depends on the situation.

I suspect, moving forwards, that these resource-intensive viewmodels will be the exception rather than the norm, but I hope that we'll see some samples/recipes posted which demonstrate some ways of handling them.

It's also likely that we'll see some people experimenting with other ongoing-resource situations - e.g. where the application needs to perform background network operations or needs to monitor geo-location beyond the lifetime of a single viewmodel (and maybe even beyond the app). Doing these sort of things in a cross-platform way is an 'interesting' pattern to consider!